# How to get the position of the checkbox checked?

Tags: php, forms

DYNAMIC FORM

```
<div class="name">
<input type="checkbox" name="mem_index[]" />
<input type="text" name="name[]" class="name" id="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]{2,}"  required=""/>
</div>
```

GETTING THE DATA OF CHECKED BOX

```
    if(isset($_POST['mem_index'])){
      $_SESSION['mem_index']=$_POST['mem_index'];
      foreach ($_SESSION['mem_index'] as $value) {
        $index=$value;
        print_r($index);
      }
    }
```

***OUTPUT***

for 1 checked box : on

for 2 checked box : onon

***GOAL***

I need the position of checked box.

OR

I need the value in the input field.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
<body>

    <div class="name">
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="checkbox" name="mem_index[]" value="1"/>
            <input type="text" name="name[]" class="name" id="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]{2,}"  />

            <input type="checkbox" name="mem_index[]" value="2"/>
            <input type="text" name="name[]" class="name" id="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]{2,}"  />

            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    foreach($_POST['mem_index'] as $checked){
        print_r($checked);
    }

    foreach($_POST['name'] as $name){
        print_r($name);
    }
}
?>
```